Avoiding EU import duty when mailing snowboard from UK then bringing it back on return flight?
I'm an Irish citizen, living in the UK. I purchased a snowboard from a UK store but it  did not arrive in time for my flight to Austria. The plan is for my brother to mail it to me in Austria (UPS a reasonable choice?), and I then bring it back on my return flight.
I will have to pay an import tax when mailing it across, is there any way I can get a refund on that tax or should I just eat the cost?

This sounds complicated and expensive. Sphero lists many of the expenses and problems, added to which a courier might take a few days to get your snowboard there. If I might suggest alternatives 1) Flights to Vienna can be found for under 20 pounds. Get someone to take your snowboard 2) rent a snowboard while you are there.

This sounds a bit complicated. I think if ~15% of the UK purchase price is not a big deal to you maybe just forget it and enjoy your holiday. The shipping cost and customs brokerage alone is likely to be in the EUR 100 range plus VAT on the value. Not all couriers will take something as long as a snowboard. BTW, get advice from the courier on valuation. I should think the declared value should be ex-VAT and inclusive of local shipping, but better to ask and avoid issues. It may have to match your invoice exactly.
The obvious approach of claiming VAT refund as you leave the EU is not going to work, IMO, because the refund comes from the seller.
